# Telerik's RadDataFilter not found

Tags: wpf, telerik

I am trying to start using Telerik's RadDataFilter.

```
 xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
```

...

```
    <telerik:RadDataFilter Name="radDataFilter" 
     Source="{Binding FirstEntries}"/>
```

But I get an error:

The tag 'RadDataFilter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation'. Line 44 Position 10.

Could you please explain to me what I am missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your project have references to Telerik.Windows.Controls.dll and Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.dll?  The [Telerik documentation for the RadDataFilter](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/datafilter-getting-started.html#sectionSectionID0EEAAA) mentions that both of these references are necessary.

I was able to reproduce the error you were getting by trying to build a project that uses a RadDataFilter but which has references to only one of the two assemblies mentioned.  When I added a reference to the second, and rebuilt, the error went away.

(Admittedly, this was with the Silverlight version of the controls.  However, the WPF and Silverlight versions of the Telerik RadControls are built from the same source code, so I expect that the WPF version of the controls will behave the same.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked. I just didn't realize there was a difference between Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.dll and Telerik.Windows.Data.dll